# Using ArcGIS ModelBuilder row iterator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I have a process with an address list as an input table. The row iterator should  iterate through entries of the address name column and then I use the output values for some other stuff.

It works for unique values (addresses). But when there are some doubled values in my input list, it just ignores those rows. I also need those similar addresses in my output.

Comment: What do you mean by double values? A picture and sample data would help people understand what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically the story around would distract from the problem since it is a question concerning a single function in ArcGIS (row iterator). Why he cannot deal with non unique input values.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you do not have uniquely identified records, i.e., there are some near or true duplicates.

According to the [ArcGIS 10.4 Interate Row Selection documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-row-selection.htm), if you set group by fields and those group by fields are the same for two records, Iterate Row Selections should skip the second record. If you do not set a group by field, the tool should just use the ObjectID to identify records in the output, and it should not skip records. Or, if you have a primary key other than ObjectID, that could work as a group by field. The documentation is a little clearer in the built-in help than the Online version I linked to.

I personally have not tried this tool using no group by fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried that last time and it didnt work. I will give it another try the upcoming days.

Comment: I dint manage to make this work. I chose a completely other way to reach my goal.